# SQL Server - How to get value from different row with multiple criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a sample table TempT:

```
Amount  | ChargeID  | IDPaymentItem | rCode | rCodeAmt | IDPayment | eDate
0.00    | 530064    | 1236182       | PR1   | 251.10   | 769630    | 04/07/2020
0.00    | 530064    | 1236182       | PR45  | 2238.90  | 769630    | 04/07/2020
188.33  | 530064    | 1240623       | CO45  | 2238.90  | 771802    | 04/30/2020
188.33  | 530064    | 1240623       | PR2   | 62.77    | 771802    | 04/30/2020
2238.90 | 530064    | 1240624       |       | 0.00     | 771803    | 04/30/2020
```

I want to create another table where the rCode would show on the corresponding row where the Amount matches the rCodeAmt, ChargeID, and eDate.

This is the code I have so far, where I am stuck:

```
DECLARE @From DATETIME
DECLARE @To DATETIME

SET @From = '{Enter starting date range: <!DATE!>}' 
SET @To = '{Enter ending date range: <!DATE!>} 23:59:59' 

SELECT
pi.Amount,
pi.ChargeID,
pi.IDPaymentItem,
pi.PatientID,
SUBSTRING(Value,0,CHARINDEX('=',Value)) AS rCode,
CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('=',Value) + 1,999999) AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(30,2)) AS rCodeAmt,
p.IDPayment,
p.eDate,
p.PaymentTypeID,
p.sDate

INTO #TempT

FROM PaymentItem pi
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ReasonCodes,',')
INNER JOIN Payment p on p.IDPayment = pi.PaymentID

WHERE p.eDate BETWEEN @From AND @To

ORDER BY pi.ChargeID

SELECT
pi.Amount,
pi.ChargeID,
pi.IDPaymentItem,
pi.PatientID,
t.rCode,
t.rCodeAmt,
p.IDPayment,
p.eDate,
p.PaymentTypeID,
p.sDate

FROM PaymentItem pi
INNER JOIN Payment p ON p.IDPayment = pi.PaymentID
FULL OUTER JOIN #TempT t ON (t.rCodeAmt = pi.Amount
                             AND t.ChargeID = pi.ChargeID)

WHERE p.eDate BETWEEN @From AND @To

ORDER BY pi.ChargeID,p.IDPayment

DROP TABLE #TempT
```

This is the result (criteria met: rCodeAmt and ChargeID).

```
Amount  | ChargeID  | IDPaymentItem | rCode | rCodeAmt | IDPayment | eDate
0.00    | 530064    | 1236182       |       |          | 769630    | 04/07/2020
188.33  | 530064    | 1240623       |       |          | 771802    | 04/30/2020
2238.90 | 530064    | 1240624       | CO45  | 2238.90  | 771803    | 04/30/2020
2238.90 | 530064    | 1240624       | PR45  | 2238.90  | 771803    | 04/30/2020
```

I can't figure out how to plug in the third criteria (eDate).

What I would like the result to be:

```
Amount  | ChargeID  | IDPaymentItem | rCode | rCodeAmt | IDPayment | eDate
0.00    | 530064    | 1236182       |       |          | 769630    | 04/07/2020
188.33  | 530064    | 1240623       |       |          | 771802    | 04/30/2020
2238.90 | 530064    | 1240624       | CO45  | 2238.90  | 771803    | 04/30/2020
```

Here is a visual if it'll help: [visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idCZI.png)

Also my expertise is beginner. Thank you!

---

Additional comment: I have tried below FROM/JOIN to add the third criteria (eDate) and it does return three rows, but the rCode values become null.

```
FROM PaymentItem pi
INNER JOIN Payment p ON p.IDPayment = pi.PaymentID
FULL OUTER JOIN #TempT t ON (t.rCodeAmt = pi.Amount
                             AND t.ChargeID = pi.ChargeID
                             AND t.eDate = p.eDate)
```

Sample:

```
Amount  | ChargeID  | IDPaymentItem | rCode | rCodeAmt | IDPayment | eDate
0.00    | 530064    | 1236182       | null  | null     | 769630    | 04/07/2020
188.33  | 530064    | 1240623       | null  | null     | 771802    | 04/30/2020
2238.90 | 530064    | 1240624       | null  | null     | 771803    | 04/30/2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below should work for you - however, the sample data you provided which was in #tempt didn't match the screenshot/it was missing some columns, so can't test with those additional columns... but the below works to return what you were asking for!

```
create table #tempt (
    Amount float
    ,ChargeID int
    ,IDPaymentItem int
    ,rCode varchar(10)
    ,rCodeAmt float
    ,IDPayment int
    ,eDate date
);

insert into #tempt select '0','530064','1236182','PR1','251.1','769630','2020-04-07'
insert into #tempt select '0','530064','1236182','PR45','2238.9','769630','2020-04-07'
insert into #tempt select '188.33','530064','1240623','CO45','2238.9','771802','2020-04-30'
insert into #tempt select '188.33','530064','1240623','PR2','62.77','771802','2020-04-30'
insert into #tempt select '2238.9','530064','1240624','','0','771803','2020-04-30'

----------------
--FINAL SELECT--
----------------
select distinct
    t.Amount
    ,t.ChargeID
    ,t.IDPaymentItem
    --,t.PatientID
    ,t1.rCode
    ,t1.rCodeAmt
    ,t.IDPayment
    ,t.eDate
    --,t.PaymentTypeID
    --,t.sDate

from
    #tempt t
    left outer join #tempt t1
        on t.amount = t1.rCodeAmt
        and t.chargeid = t1.chargeid
        and t.edate = t1.edate
```

Comment: Hi Toni! Thank you for the response, unfortunately it did not work. It does give me the three rows that I want, but the rCode column becomes null.

Comment: from the screenshot, you wanted the first two rows to have rCode as null and the last one with a value - is the screenshot not correct?

Comment: The screenshot is correct, but with your code all the values/rows are null in the rCode column.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code exactly and it does work, but I am not defining the #TempT table. So maybe that is where the issue is.

Comment: Hi Toni! Just wanted to say that the issue was with the date format. Without your answer I wouldn't have been able to see that. You also showed me a cleaner way of doing the final select. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Cool beans - glad I could help :) make sure to accept an answer so the question closes!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had to convert the date first in order for date = date to work.

Originally I wasn't sure if date = date as a third criteria would work since I've never joined that much before.

When Toni showed me that yes, it does work, but for some reason it still wouldn't work for me I knew the problem was with the date. The only thing I could think of is the formatting, so I tried that and it worked.

TempT

```
CAST(p.eDate AS DATE) AS eDate
```

Final Select

```
CONVERT(datetime,t.eDate,101) AS eDate
```